# Installing CUDA for Neural Networks driver

Tags: command-line, drivers, software-installation, cuda

I'm totally new to ubuntu, and I have a problem in installing cuDNN. I'm following this guide, and currently in step 3:
https://www.learnopencv.com/installing-deep-learning-frameworks-on-ubuntu-with-cuda-support/

I downloaded the cuDNN v6.0 Library for Linux file (was saved to Downloads). Ran this command line:

```
tar xvf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0.tgz
```

So good so far. Now I have a cuda library - `/home/nimrod/Downloads/cuda/`. I'm having a problem with this line:

```
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

Edit: I get "cp: target '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/' is not a directory"

No idea what should I type. I tried:

```
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/* /nimrod/Downloads/cuda/lib64/
```

and

```
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/* home/nimrod/Downloads/cuda/lib64/
```

and a few other combinations. What should I do?

Edit: @dessert's suggestion of using mkdir solved the problem with the second line (odd, because I had that library). Now I have a problem with the third line, I get the following:
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/cuda/include/': Not a directory

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't need to change a thing* in this command, just run all three commands from within the same directory, e.g. `/home/nimrod/Downloads` in your case. Let's `cd` to there to be sure:

```
cd /home/nimrod/Downloads
sudo cp -P cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp cuda/include/* /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

Alternatively you can give the commands the *full paths*:

```
sudo cp -P /home/nimrod/Downloads/cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp /home/nimrod/Downloads/cuda/include/* /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

Comment: I've already tried that, that's why I was trying other things. That's what I get when I type the second line: cp: target '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/' is not a directory

Comment: @Niminim That's crucial information and belongs in your question, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/982404/edit) and add it. Alright, just create the directory then: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

Comment: You're right. I've just added that. Anyway, I do have that library, so it's odd.

Comment: there was such library so it should have worked. Anyway, after using the mkdir second line works fine. Now I have a problem with third line. I get: "cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/cuda/include/': Not a directory" . How do I solve that?

Comment: @Niminim Does it say `Not a directory` or rather `No such file or directory`? If the latter just create this dir as well with `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda/include` (can't do any harm anyway).

Comment: It says "cannot create regular file..." exactly I mentioned above.

Comment: Really odd, seems like it works now :)